# How to disable Specflow intellisense?

Tags: specflow

My project is very large and has a huge number of test steps. As a result, when I am writing 'feature' files I find my computer grinds to a halt. On very large feature files, even without typing anything, one of my CPU cores will max out, and performance will degrade to the point where typing is extremely laggy, forcing me to restart Visual Studio.

Even on smaller feature files, the performance when writing feature files is also extremely slow as the Specflow intellisense looks at all the test steps in the project.

Is there a way to disable the Specflow intellisense or even to stop Specflow from analysing step bindings? Is there anything at all I can do to improve performance here?

Comment: You could edit the files in Notepad++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable intellisense by going to Tools -> Options -> SpecFlow -> Editor settings -> Enable Intellisense.

[image]

But I am afraid that it will just stop showing that in IDE, but analysis continue, so it won't solve your CPU issue (according to [the code](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.VisualStudio/blob/19d91981b14865686b8ea7823e860861e3d88f96/VsIntegration/AutoComplete/GherkinStepCompletionSource.cs#L35))

But the option "Enable project-wide analysis" set to False should solve your problem

Comment: Disabling intellisense should fix the performance issue. The project wide analysis runs the first time you open a feature file after you open a solution, and is cached. The site wide analysis is most likely not the issue.

Comment: I turned off both project-wide analysis and intellisense and I have not yet experienced my CPU having a freakout, so that's good :)