# Disable IntelliSense for Specflow feature files in VS 2022

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022, specflow

Is there any way of disabling intellisense suggestions and autocomplete in Specflow *.feature files?

I'm writing Scenario description (which is in natural language) and it keeps suggesting and autocomplete the text which turns me crazy. I would expect this to behave like writing a comment. It's a plain text so (dear intellisense) don't suggest me types from the solution.

[I found that there was option for disabling intellisense in Specflow options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710080/how-to-disable-specflow-intellisense) but in [Visual Studio 2022 these options are not available anymore](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/visualstudio/settings-options.html). They say it is replaced with specflow.json configuration file which has a [defined schema](https://specflow.org/wp-content/uploads/specflowconfigs/specflow-config.json) but I'm not able to figure out how to disable intellisense suggestions using this schema. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IntelliSense/ Visual Studion wasn't behaving normally because of long running without termination (VS or even System).

Good old restart of the computer helped and now it is working as expected.